# Automatically add new sheet to cell calculation in Excel / Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Is it possible to add a new created table sheet to a cell calculation, where a specific cell of all table sheets is added together and shown in that cell?

I need to add a sheet for every project, and I need a sum of one cell of all projects, and I don't want to add all new created sheets to that calculation manually.

Is there a way to do it? Mainly for Google Spreadsheets, but I think it would be nearly the same for Excel?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `Is it possible to add a new created table sheet to a cell calculation, where a specific cell of all table sheets is added together and shown in that cell?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I mean those table sheets you can add to you whole excel file by clicking the "plus" symbol at the bottom left.
I want to have a function, that knwos every sheet existing and new added, and that sums up every same field in every of those sheets. All sheets are the same. You can think of every sheet as a Project with costs maybe, and I want to add them. And it should be easy to to add a new project without editing the function that sums all together.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that your question is for Excel file which is not Google Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Comment: I think its nearly the same. You can import and export both like it's the same.
I thought about using macros for that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal. So I cannot understand about the solution. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: I have a document with more than one sheet, or page. On the first page I would like to have a sum of an aspect of all following pages.
I can add cells from different sheets / pages with something like this:
```
=IF(C4="";"";SUMIFS($'Sheet 1'.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet 2'.C$4:C$496;C4))
```
But when I want to add a "Sheet 3", I need to add it to the calculation manually. I want to avoid that, maybe by automativally add that "Sheet 3" to that calculation by some magic :D

But thank you a lot for replying :D

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to put the formula of `=IF(C4="";"";SUMIFS($'Sheet3'.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet3'.C$4:C$496;C4))` when `Sheet3` is added. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, when I add "Sheet 3", the formular should change from `=IF(C4="";"";SUMIFS($'Sheet 1'.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet 2'.E$4:E$496;C4))` to `=IF(C4="";"";SUMIFS($'Sheet 1'.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet 2'.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet 3.E$4:E$496;C4))`
(sorry, the previous code example weren't correct, but slightly).
And when I add another sheet, it should change to `=IF(C4="";"";SUMIFS($'Sheet 1'.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet 2'.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet 3.E$4:E$496;$'Sheet 4.E$4:E$496;C4))`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic of what you expect in your reply. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. Can you update your question by including the detail information about your goal? By this, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Well, I have this calulaction:
`=SUM($'Project 1'.E$1)`
Everytime I add another sheet to my excel file, I want my calculation to know about that file, like:
`=SUM($'Project 1'.E$1;$'New created sheet'.E$1)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems that [your latest reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469001/automatically-add-new-sheet-to-cell-calculation-in-excel-google-spreadsheet?noredirect=1#comment108738265_61469001) is different from [the prebious reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469001/automatically-add-new-sheet-to-cell-calculation-in-excel-google-spreadsheet?noredirect=1#comment108738040_61469001). I'm confusing about what you want to do. Can you give me a time to understand about your goal? This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wonder where is your criteria range in your fomula ? As long as I know the sumifs formula should be something like this `=SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range1,criteria1)` ?